# IIS Connect As: Does website visitor inherit rights of specified account?

Tags: iis, azure

I have IIS on an Azure VM pointing to an Azure File Share for the website files/contents.

To allow IIS to access the File Share, I created an account on the VM with the same credentials as the File Share account, and then set the Connect As for that site to said user.  To be clear the Connect As user has full read/write permissions.

Q: Will anonymous IIS site visitors inherit the Connect As user rights, thus leaving a rather large hole in my site security?

Comment: Why does the user being used by IIS have write permissions?

Comment: As best I can tell only Microsoft accounts can be added as rights managed users to Azure file share, and I don't believe you can add a Microsoft account as a user on Windows server.